# Can I use geom_path or geom_line length in ggplot2 as a variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a script involving mobility mapping in R. I am using ggplot, ggmap, and stamenmap to do this.
I would like to be able to use the length of geom_path as a variable in order to separate those who travel long distances from those who travel short distances, etc. Before I get too far into this, can path or line length be used as a variable? If so, how do I access it?

Comment: No. ggplot will not calculate the length of the path for you. You'd have to calculate this value before creating the plot. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick. This was just a simple question that I could not find any information about, so I assumed ggplot did not include that anyway. I am working with coordinates, so I suppose I will have to calculate max distance for each person with good ol' Pythagoras.

Comment: To calculate a geospatial path, take a look the "geosphere" package.